# insert rows in pandas dataframe based on string in one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe looks like

```
Name score
A;A;B 5
C;C;A 6
```

I want to make it without using any for loop

```
Name  score
A  5
B  5
C  6
A  6
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with splitted values by `;` and then [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.assign(Name = df['Name'].str.split(';'))
        .explode('Name')
        .drop_duplicates(['Name','score'], ignore_index=True))
print (df)
  Name  score
0    A      5
1    B      5
2    C      6
3    A      6
```

Comment: Not working. It is adding one column, but not appending new rows.

Comment: @user10340258 - what is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: it worked for test dataframe, but not for the real dataframe. not clear to me. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: @user10340258 - what is difference with real data?

Comment: Only the shape is big (293444, 2). After applying the code it is becoming (293444, 3). Also, all indices are not present. I checked with ignore_index = False. It does not help.

Comment: @user10340258 - if test first 10 rows it working? `df.head(10).assign(Name = df['Name'].str.split(';')) .explode('Name').drop_duplicates(['Name','score'], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @user10340258 - is there separator `;` in real data?

Comment: your code has worked with the real data also. I only renamed the columns. Earlier column names contained underscores which I removed. It is not clear to me why underscore mattered. Anyways, thanks a lot.